# $|p_{n+1}-q|\leq c|p_n - q|$ implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} p_n = q$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $|p_{n+1}-q|\leq c|p_n - q|$ for all $n$ and $c<1$. Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} p_n = q$

My Attempted solution:
Well, I don't really know. I just want to ask for a hint on how should I start this.

Comment: Try to show that $|p_n-q| \le Kc^n$ for some $K$. You can do that by induction (if $|c| < 1$ - I assume you miswrote somewhere).

Comment: Please start by copying correctly your homework. And yes, add some personal input (at present there is none whatsoever).

Comment: Not true: take $p_n=2$ for all $n$ ,$q=1$ and $c=100$.

Comment: Isn't $\;c\color{red}<1$?

Comment: As others have said you probably mean $c<1$. I would do it by contradiction.

Comment: sorry, I already corrected it :) Thanks for the point out.

Answer (score 2):

**Let's assume** $0\leq c<1$.

**Hint.** You may observe that you have
$$
\begin{align}
|p_{n+1}-q|
&\leq c\:|p_{n}-q|\\\\
&\leq c\times c\:|p_{n-1}-q|\\\\
&\leq c\times c \times c \:|p_{n-2}-q|\\\\
&\leq \cdots \\\\
&\leq c^{n+1} \:|p_{0}-q|. 
\end{align}
$$ Then use
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty}c^n=0,\quad |c|<1,
$$ to conclude.